# some objects not showing in render

Tags: rendering, objects

I have made a walk cycle with deadpool. Deadpool shows up in the render but i added cubes and cylinders to make the deadpool logo, they don't show up in the render. If i add another cube, i can't see it either. I checked all the camera icons so that's not the problem. I have searched the internet but i couldn't find any good. I have added my blender file. I hope someone has the answer.

[blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2asbvtrl03xdk2/deadpool%20met%20logo.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of blender interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to have gotten out of sync in your scene, and looks like you are in some sort of "Isolation Mode".

Hitting <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> (Slash key from number pad) twice to enter and exit *Local View* seems to somehow fix it.

Also mind your materials, you seem to have *Blender Internal* materials mixed with Cycles ones.

Comment: Isolation mode indicates "local" in the upper left corner of the 3D view.

Comment: Old habits die hard, still calling it "isolation mode" when the true name is *Local View*, fixed now. Also, upon closer inspection you are right, the scene was **not** in *Local view* which is strange, but somehow entering and exiting seems to have fixed whatever was wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked! Now i can finish my animation @DuarteFarrajotaRamos